# Postman - Not able to send request with client_credentials grant_type

Tags: postman

[image]I am trying to get an accessToken from Microsoft Graph API using Postman tool. I am trying it in Authorization tab with Type=oauth2.0, so that I can use this accessToken for subsequent Get,Post requests.

Everything works fine, if the grant_type is "Authorization Code". But when the grant_type is **client_credentials**, postman throws the below error

> error getting access token from client_credentials flow. Could not
>   send request

I have looked at the Network tab in DeveloperTools, it does not submit  Client_Id, Client_Secret for client_credentials flow.

**Question:**  How can I get Postman work for **client_credentials** grant_type scenario?

Am I missing any step here? Please guide me..

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'm late to the party on this, but hopefully if someone else looks for this, they can find it, since we ran into the same issue.

The previous two answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65708126/6772160 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270148/6772160) guided us in the right direction, but we still had to *translate* this to work properly in Postman:

As Mahmoud mentioned, you can send in the `client_id` and the `client_secret` as basic auth:
[Basic Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKmU6.png)

The main part is handling the `grant_type` as `client_credentials` though. To do that, we input:

`grant_type=client_credentials` in the Body of the request.

Click Body > select x-www-form-urlencoded > key = `grant_type` and value = `client_credentials`.

The Body tab should look like this when completed:
[Body Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSKrd.png)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. Since we can't guarantee that the answers will stay in the same order over time, it's best to link to the specific answers you are referencing.  The statement "The previous two answers..." should become confusing.

Comment: Definitely. Just made that edit above. Thanks!

Comment: In my comment, Should = could.  Appreciate the update!

Answer (score 1):

Try providing the following details:

```
Request Type: POST
URL: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/token?grant_type=client_credentials
Authorization: Basic [client_id]:[client_secret]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The output should look like:

```
{
    "access_token": "90778b6abce64fc124892ce66f7a8ecd",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 60,
    "scope": ""
}
```

**Note:** Provide `[client_id]:[client_secret]` as BASE64Encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You should send it as a `raw` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` data as in the following example:

> Important header >>>> `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
var data = "grant_type=client_credentials";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://########/oauth/v2/token");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic ###############");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send(data);
```